# Where does the energy go in a Power Rabi experiment with superconducting circuits?

Tags: experimental-realization

When performing a Power-Rabi experiment, e.g in superconducting circuits, we are playing a pulse to a qubit and then reading out its state by playing another pulse to a dispersively-coupled readout resonator. We are repeating this process many times for different amplitudes of the pulse to the qubit, and we can see oscillations in the averaged state of the qubit as a function of the amplitude. This is the Rabi oscillation phenomenon which is very well understood, and has a very simple mathematical model. However, it is rather weird that even though we are increasing the energy flow to the qubit, it is starting to lose energy. Since I expect energy conservation, my question is where this energy is going?